# Обратная операция с .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

Как проделать обратную операцию с .gitignore? Удалить строку с нужным файлом, а дальше?
Необходимо чтобы файл появился. git pull не помог.

Comment: gitignore не влияет на подтягиваемые файлы, насколько знаю. Опишите ситуацию детальней, непонятно откуда файл должен был взяться.

Answer (score 3):

`.gitignore` просто не дает вам добавить в репозиторий ненужные файлы по маске. Когда вы делаете `pull` все выкачивается в полном объеме и `.gitignore` на этот процесс никак не влияет.

Comment: Получается этого файла нет вообще в репозитарии, раз я его не наблюдаю?

Comment: нет в текущей ветке, по крайней мере